# angular 8 ngx-formly datetimepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

i'm trying to make datetimepicker by [ngx-formly](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly)

After i read all the examples in [offical docs](https://formly.dev/examples/introduction) , i still have no idea how to make it.

Is there any custom form field or build in datetimepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for custom field type https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field,
to summarize here are the required steps:

1. Create a custom [field type](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field)  with name `datetimepicker`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-datetimepicker',
 template: `
   <datetimepicker [formControl]="formControl"></datetimepicker>
 `,
})
export class DatetimepickerFieldType extends FieldType {}
```

2. define your field type through the `NgModule` declaration:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [DatetimepickerFieldType],
 imports: [
   ....
   FormlyModule.forRoot({
     types: [
       { name: 'datetimepicker', component: DatetimepickerFieldType },
     ],
   }),
 ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. set type to `type` in your field config:

```
fields = [
  {
    key: 'datetimepicker',
    type: 'datetimepicker',
  },
]
```

still confused check formly UI source code https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/tree/master/src/ui

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind relying on the browser's built-in date and time pickers, you can just set a regular Formly field's `templateOptions.type` to `datetime-local` (or `date` or `time`, if you only need one or the other) and this will be passed through to the html `<input>` element. No custom field necessary! Though obviously you will have less control over the user experience than if you made your own datetimepicker.

Mozilla has details on usage, browser compatibility, etc. for the [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) type, as well as date and time.

Comment: Note, in @ngx-formly 6 the attribute to use is `props.type`. eg
`{
  key: 'fromDate',
  type: 'input',
  props: {
    label: 'From Date',
    required: true,
    type: 'date'
  }
}`